# Nullify column values of deleted rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

For example, I have these tables and data:

```
TABLE: logo_user
+----+---------+
| id | logo_id |
+----+---------+
| 1  | 1       |
| 2  | 2       |
+----+---------+

TABLE: logo
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
| 2  |
+----+
```

What I want is to delete every rows in `logo` table, and nullify the values that refers to it. Example:

```
TABLE: logo_user
+----+---------+
| id | logo_id |
+----+---------+
| 1  | NULL    |
| 2  | NULL    |
+----+---------+

TABLE: logo (now emptied)
```

- I tried using `TRUNCATE ... CASCADE` but it also deleted every rows in the `logo_user` table.
- I also consider altering the foreign key constraint of the `logo_user` to cascade on delete, but it's too much work. In reality I have many tables referring to `logo` table.

Comment: Using a FK with `on delete set null` is the only "automatic" way of doing this. It will be a lot less work then changing each every delete statement to deal with all related tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below solution for your problem.

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

on a foreign key in your main table will solve the problem in one step. What it basically does is : 
if a record in the parent table is deleted, then the corresponding records in the child table will have the foreign key fields set to null (the columns that you would be mentioning in the key). The records in the child table will not be deleted, the corresponding values would be updated to null as per your requirement. For example you can refer to the below syntax :

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
 (
 column1 datatype null/not null,
 column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

 CONSTRAINT fk_col
 FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
 REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
 ON DELETE SET NULL
 );
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: added  an explanation :) @TobySpeight

Comment: Thanks for this! I have altered your solution a little. Instead of creating a table, I updated the `logo_user` tables by dropping its foreign key constraint and adding it again with `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it's "too much work" to modify the foreign keys to `ON DELETE SET NULL` - it's not just the easiest way, you will have to do it since the default `NO ACTION` will prevent you from deleting without a cascade.